# Como obtener 'value' de DataTable de una fila seleccionada con checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Carga la tabla a traves de una peticion AJAX la cual me retorna todos los datos y
usando la propiedad **ColumnDefs.className** indico que sea **'select-checkbox'** junto con el
selector '**td:first-child'**

```
let addContainer = $('#tableAddContainers').DataTable(
        {
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: 0,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '',
                    ordenable: false,
                    className: 'select-checkbox'
                }
            ],
            select:{
                style: 'multi',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[1, 'asc']],
            ajax: {
                url: '/home/partidas/getContainers/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {data: ''},
                {data: 'idContenedor'},
                {data: 'noContenedor'},
                {data: 'tipoContenedor'},
                {data: 'fechaEntrada'}
            ]
        }
    );
```

Me encuentro confundido pues al ser solo etiquetas **td** no concibo forma de poder obtener los datos de '**columns**'

He visto varios videos en donde obtienen el id del checkbox mas no de las columnas registradas como data,
posteriormente intente realizar la siguiente prueba sin exito

```
$('#tableAddContainers tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var data = addContainer.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        alert(data[0] + "contenedor id es: " + data[3]);
    });
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML donde se encuentra tu tabla, [editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/edit) tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice eso recientemente sacar el valor de una columna te muestro como lo hice espero te sirva.

```
        var ignicion = $('#tbodyGPSXDia #'+id+' td:nth-child(7) span').html();
        var posicion = $('#tbodyGPSXDia #'+id+' td:nth-child(8) span').html();
        var panico = $('#tbodyGPSXDia #'+id+' td:nth-child(9) span').html();
        var mOn = $('#tbodyGPSXDia #'+id+' td:nth-child(10) span').html();
        var mOff = $('#tbodyGPSXDia #'+id+' td:nth-child(11) span').html();
```

lo que hago en estas líneas es obtener el valor de las columnas 7,8,9,10,11 y agregue la etiqueta span por que el valor que yo ocupo está dentro un span así:
[image: Ejemplo demostración]

Como puedes ver a cada fila le asigno un id que yo traigo desde mi consulta DB para poder identificar la fila que quiero.

[image: Vista de la tabla]

Al final solo agrego estos valores a una función para ocuparlos como yo desee.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva mi ejemplo.